# Pass arguments to ng-submit and reset input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
i have little modified this question which already exist
    <form ng-submit="add()">
      <input type="text" name="field">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

I'd like to have `input[name="field"]` value as a parameter of `add()`. 
  Is there any way to do that?

Answer to question

Html:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyFormController">
      <form ng-submit="add(field)">
        <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </form>
   </div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MyFormController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
   scope.add = function(field) { // <-- here is you value from the input 
     // ...
   };
}]);
```

my problem is

HOW to reset input field to be empty after form submit in this case

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should be like that:

```
 <div ng-controller="MyFormController">
      <form ng-submit="add()">
        <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="fieldname" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </form>
   </div>
```

and your JS field should be like that:

```
app.controller("MyFormController", function($scope) {
  $scope.add = function () {
      var hi=$scope.fieldname;//you can use it parametre
  }
});
```

Comment: @shabir ullah Please follow this link https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-submit.asp Ithink it will solve your problem

Comment: @shabir ullah if it is solved your problem,then please accept my answer

Comment: when i pass input ng-model as parameter than it working in other cases not working yet

Comment: <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field" /> have you changed the value of  name="field" and ng-model="field"? they will be different value

Comment: yes i try for both that is ng-model and name both same and also change means with different

Comment: the problem is with clearing(reset) the input field. there is no problem with data

Comment: this is my html code:<form ng-submit="myFunc()">
  <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="txtvalue">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>{{myTxt}}</p> and this is my JS code app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myTxt = "You have not yet clicked submit";
  $scope.myFunc = function () {
    var hi=$scope.txtvalue;
      $scope.myTxt =  hi;
  }
}); it works for me as you want

Comment: console.log(hi) or console.log($scope.fieldname) you will get nothing

Comment: @shabir ullah,it works for me could you share me your code

Comment: but in this example some manual values are added in my scenario i does not need to assign some thing to $scope.myTxt?

Answer (score 1):

After two days googling i found my solution with this statement

give an id to the input field for example 'clearfield' and than add the following

statement after the .success function

angular.element('#clearfield').val('');

Comment: Exactly I also with the same problem. Worked.:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass this as an argument. Since your input has a `ng-model="field"` this is a `$scope` variable which is accessible in your function already

```
app.controller('MyFormController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
   $scope.add = function() { 
     // your code here
     $scope.field = ''; // reset field to an empty string
   };
}]);
```

Comment: i am using app.controller('MyFormController', function($scope,$http) { is there any difference between these two formates

Comment: you will need to provide a more complete code example and describe what "not working" means

Comment: when i pass ng-model as argument to the function than it passes the value of input but without it , it does not show model value